# Как изменить класс в html через javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет, передо мной встала задача, я у меня есть код на python который рассчитывает нагрузку на процессор и озу, через js я делаю запрос к API и вывожу полученные данные в переменные.
Как исходя из значения переменной изменить класс в теге <div class="> в html?

Answer (score 1):

По-разному можно. Зависит что надо

```js
let el = document.querySelector('.test');
let number = 10;

// Можно так
if (number < 10) {
  el.textContent = 'Мало %(';
  el.classList.remove('hello');
  el.classList.add('hello2');
}

// А Можно так
if (number === 10) {
    el.textContent = 'О, нормас так :-)';
    el.classList.toggle('hello');
}
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
}

.hello {
    background: blue;
}

.hello2 {
    background: yellow;
}

.hello3 {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```